# Facebook API login - issue around redirect_uri recently (Facebook Connect)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using the facebook auth in my app for the past 4 months - and all of a sudden (2 days) ago it stopped working with the following exception.

Note: the redirect_uri has not changed in this 4 months as well.

**Question: Any ideas why i am getting this exception out of nowhere now?**

> API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error
>   Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted
>
> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=11111111&redirect_uri=http://test.test.us/application/web/index.php5?facebooklogin=1&scope=email,read_stream

.. = redacted actual domain name, client id

Answer (score 0):

You can't place a URL as a query parameter without encoding it first.  How you get that encoded URL is dependent on your programming language.  In PHP, it's the urlencode() function, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test.us%2Fapplication%2Fweb%2Findex.php5%3Ffacebooklogin%3D1%26scope%3Demail%2Cread_stream
```

Comment: I am using UrlEncode around it - like i said it has been working for 4months, suddenly stopeed working a few days back. Anyone from Facebook can provide insight into why?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we had the same problem:
Our app was hosted on two servers: Dev and Live.
On the dev-server everything worked fine (it has a normal www.domain.tld address).
On the live-server (on a subdomain) we get the message:

> API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error
>   Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

The odd thing is: When I save the app-config in facebook, it works sometimes for some minutes.
Then after some minutes it magically don't work anymore (with the error message above).

Our solution:
Move the live-server from the subdomain to a normal www-domain. Now everything works fine.

I wonder if this is intended (to prevent shared hosters) or a major bug...